# Permission denied: connect occurs on Selenium 2.44.0

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am using Selenium 2.44.0 to test my web projects but whenever I run the program, it just stops the test then throws an error saying this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFoSF.png

My code for launching the browser is:

```
try {
    ff.setPreference("permissions.default.image", 2);
    driver = new FirefoxDriver(ff);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get(baseUrl);
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your browser is failing. A quick fix to this problem is to download and install Firefox 28.", "Oppss..", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
```

Is there a way to fix this error? I didn't use the selenium-server-standalone, I used selenium-java. Do I need to switch from using selenium-java to selenium-server-standalone?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are experiencing *compatibility issues between selenium 2.44 and Firefox 35*: either **upgrade to selenium 2.45** which was released couple days ago, or **downgrade your Firefox to 34.0.5**.

Comment: Ok. I have upgraded the selenium to 2.45.0 (selenium-java-2.45.0.jar). I'll run it on the computer that experiences this error because it seems like only some computers are affected. Thank you.

Comment: I got more issues with the Selenium 2.45.0 and Firefox 34.0.5. I'm switching back to Selenium 2.44.0 and Firefox 28.